Starlink Satellites launching by SpaceX
Starlink Satellites launching by SpaceX
Starlink Satellite Launching news 1
Starlink Satellite launching news 2
Theoretically and practically, how many maximum Starlink Satellites can be launched by SpaceX to avoid interference with other satellites to provide internet connectivity in countries?

What specifically do you mean by "interference"? Space is very, very, big. While traffic management would get more difficult, there is essentially no realistically achievable limit to how many satellites could be launched into orbit.

I mean collision.

Radio frequencies are typically allocated in such a way that interference is impossible or at least very unlikely.
Each jurisdiction has its own regulatory agency, for example, in the US, it is the FCC which licenses specific frequency bands to (not only) satellite operators, in Germany, it is the BNetzA. These agencies are responsible for licensing a part of the spectrum to be used in a specific area, they monitor interference, and detect unlicensed transmissions.
Because all these agencies can only license frequencies within their own jurisdictions, a satellite operator such as SpaceX needs to obtain licenses from every single regulatory agencies whose territories they overfly, or alternatively, they need to switch off their radios while overflying that territory. Which is precisely what they are doing.
This means it is unlikely that there will be any problems with interference with other satellites, regardless of how many Starlink satellites there are. Currently, SpaceX has applied for an FCC license for a second-generation constellation of 29998 satellites. The FCC has granted a license for 7500 of those, and deferred the decision on the others until such a time that SpaceX is actually getting ready to launch them. So far, SpaceX have only launched 6698 Starlink satellites in total, i.e., for both the Generation 1 and Generation 2 constellations, of which 477 have reentered, 6221 are in orbit, and 6149 are in operation.
So, the FCC has already validated that 7500 Starlink satellites in the Gen 2 constellation plus however many there are in Gen 1, won't cause any interference, otherwise, they wouldn't have granted the license. And if the FCC thought there were any serious problems with the full constellation, they would have outright denied the license, not deferred the decision.
We can see that the process is working, because earlier this year, the FCC denied SpaceX's request to allocate additional frequencies to Starlink for the mobile Starlink service because it does not comply with current regulations. However, the FCC also invited the public to submit comments on a request by SpaceX to change those current regulations.
